# Searching nested lists of int

Tags: python, recursion

How can i write a recursive function that returns true if the given 'to_find' is found in the given nested lists.

ex:

```
>>> searchNested([1,[4, 5, 6, [2, 10], 9], [1, 4, 5]], 2)
True
```

Comment: Have you already tried something?

Answer (score 3):

```
def searchNested(xs, y):
    if y == xs:
        return True
    return isinstance(xs, list) and any(searchNested(x, y) for x in xs)
```

---

```
>>> searchNested([1,[4, 5, 6, [2, 10], 9], [1, 4, 5]], 2)
True
>>> searchNested([1,[4, 5, 6, [8, 10], 9], [1, 4, 5]], 2)
False
```

Answer (score 0):

Flatten first, then use `in`

```
def searchNested(lst,needle):
    def flatten(target):
        return_list = list()
        for element in target:
            if isinstance(element,list):
                return_list.extend(flatten(element))
            else:
                return_list.append(element)
        return return_list

    lst = flatten(lst)
    if needle in lst: return True
    else: return False
```

Comment: You can condense the last part to just: `return needle in flatten(lst)`.